# How to scan using SANE from docker container?

Tags: docker, sane

I have an old wifi printer/scanner HP Photosmart B209a. I can print and scan from the host machine, but I would like to print and scan from the Docker container.

Printing is working: the image has CUPS installed, I copy /etc/cups/printers.conf from host machine, start cupsd - and viola, printing is fine.

But I don't know how to configure SANE to find the scanner. Where is SANE config located? Which files should I copy from the host machine? Are there any limitations which would prevent my scanner from working from the container?